# How to track/manage runnables in Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, rx-java

In my code I need to implement instant spam action for message. For this I change my message without waiting for server response. But sometime on server request errors I need to revert my message state to original. `handler.removeCallbacks(runnable)` not letting me know whether runnable has already run. How I can accomplish this? I also open to other suggestions to perform these delayed jobs via RxJava, or other technologies.

```
var handler = Handler()

fun spamMessage(originalMessage: ContentMessage) {
        var runnable: Runnable? = null
        val modifiedMessage = originalMessage.cloneUsingJson()

        if (modifiedMessage != null) {
            modifiedMessage.setSpamReported(true)
            runnable = Runnable {
                updateMessage(message)
            }
            updateWithDelay(runnable)
        }

        ApiClient.service.spamMessage(message.serverId).subscribeAsync(subscriptions, object : ApiSubscriberNew<Void>() {
            override fun onFailure() {
                var canceled : Boolean = handler.removeCallbacks(runnable)
                if (!canceled) {
                    //if couldn't cancel, or was late, revert the changes
                    revertMessageUpdate(originalMessage)
                }

            }

        })
    }

private fun updateWithDelay(runnable: Runnable) {
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 100)
}
```

Comment: There is no direct API to achieve this, but you can set a class variable (boolean) from your runnable and check that var later.

Comment: I think I can achieve this by having object that will have both positive runnable and revertRunnable and flag for runnable completed action. Then I can check whether this action is completed or not.